# Targeting an element with URL hash

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can I target #collapse-1 instead of #1

I've tried using a substring but I'm doing something wrong.

```
    var hash = window.location.hash;
    var anchor = $('a[href$="'+hash+'"]');
        if (anchor.length > 0){
            anchor.click();
        }
    });
```

Comment: Can you please explain more? How are you expecting us to know your question with just reading this?

Comment: I'm trying to open an accordion with a url, I'm able to target using a hash with just a number but I need to add collapse- to the beginning. So instead of #1 (or any number) it needs to be #collapse-1 (or any number) heres an example I found https://www.digiplek.nl/open-jquery-ui-panel-via-an-external-link-url-with-hash.html#1

Comment: @AustinRedd Please edit and update your question with relevant information, don't leave it as a comment.

Comment: @AustinRedd I updated the answer thats all you need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1.Assign hash to a variable:

```
var hash = window.location.hash;
```

2.Remove the "#" from hash and Add the collapse word:

```
var newHash = "#collapse-" + hash.replace('#','');
```

3.Then:

```
var anchor = $('a[href$="'+newHash+'"]');
        if (anchor.length > 0){
            anchor.click();
        }
    });
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, seems like that should be working but it's not and its not throwing any errors. I edited the first bit of code from `windows` to `window`

Comment: console.log the newHash and see what is the output

Comment: `#collapse-collapse-2` its so close! any idea why there are two collapses? Edit: the url is .html#collapse-2

Comment: that means your application is adding collapse already and you dont need to add another collapse

Comment: Got it to work by calling hash instead of new hash.

Comment: which means it was already working haha

Comment: No idea why it wasn't working before, maybe I had a typo, regardless I learned some things. Thank you

Comment: Your welcome, glad to be a help at least

Answer (score 0):

You can set `window.location.hash`: https://jsfiddle.net/jbw4Lz0s/4/

```
function jump(link) {
    window.location.hash = link;
}
```